# How to iterate over tuple index in django template

Tags: python, django-templates, tuples

Suppose i have this

`mylst = [(a, b, c), (x, y, z), (l, m, n)]`

now instead of having this

```
{\% for item in mylst \%}    
     {{ item.0 }} {{ item.1}} {{ item.2 }}    
{\% endfor \%}
```

can i have another loop like

```
{\% for item in mylst \%}    
     {\% for a in item.length \%}
             {{item.index  }}
     {\% endfor \%}
{\% endfor \%}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and you don't want to. Iterate through the inner list in exactly the same way as the outer one.

```
{% for item in mylst %}
    {% for a in item %}
        {{ a }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```